# Android: FATAL Exception MAIN

Tags: android, crash, fatal-error

I am getting the following logs and my activity is crashing for some unknown reason.
This problem might be related to admob.. Please suggest what to do.

```
            02-18 22:30:45.122: W/dalvikvm(8179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
            02-18 22:30:45.232: V/webview(8179): destroy : called.
            02-18 22:30:45.232: V/webview(8179): destroy : called.
            02-18 22:30:45.232: V/webview(8179): destroy : called.
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:625)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.uiOverrideUrlLoading(CallbackProxy.java:229)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:336)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: E/AndroidRuntime(8179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            02-18 22:30:45.252: W/ActivityManager(175):   Force finishing activity com.xyz.android/.SelectActivity
```

Best Regards

Comment: See the Stack Trace it says "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Comment: @323go I am sorry. I have no idea, which code is causing this issue. I am fixing a big application..

Comment: `Force finishing activity com.xyz.android/.SelectActivity`

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some weird bug with admob. Using the latest jar fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're launching an Intent from either a Broadcast Receiver or some kind of Service. As these components do not have a UI attached to them, you need the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` attached to your Intent. Try something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```